# Integrating C# and Matlab

Tags: c#, matlab, visual-studio-2012

I've encountered a problem while integrating MATLAB and C# by VS WFApplication. The code is the following and the error is related to the line marked with '>>'.

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
    {
       public partial class Form1 : Form
       {
           private void Mlab_call()
           {
               MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();
               matlab.Execute(@"C:\Users\mlab");
               object RESULT = null;
      >>       matlab.Feval("multiply", 1, out RESULT, 3.14, 42.0, "world");
               object[] Calibration = RESULT as object[];   
           }
       }
    }
```

> Error: Unexpected MATLAB operator.

Might it be caused by the version of VS and Matlab?
Could you suggest any other solution to integrate them in the same C# project?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that `multiply` is the correct nominal call for Matlab multiplicaton operator. Try:

```
matlab.Feval("times", 1, out RESULT, 3.14, 42.0);
```

If you run `times(2,3)` on Matlab console, the output is `6`.

Comment: "multiply" is a matlab function. I made and saved it in the mlab folder.

Comment: Well, you should really post it then. Debugging invisible code is far away from my reach. Also... do you also get the line and the name of the function where the error occurs? That's quite important too.